# Python urllib2 and dynamically loaded data

Tags: python, urllib2

I am using `urllib2` in Python and I am trying to download a list of news stories from: http://web.tmxmoney.com/news.php?qm_symbol=CM

This is working, however, when I try to download from:
http://web.tmxmoney.com/news.php?qm_symbol=CM#qmpage2 (and subsequent pages), the results are always the same as the first page.

I am loading the data into a string with the following command:

```
contents = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

I am not sure how the data is loaded on the into the php page in the background but it seems to happen slightly after the load rather than as a direct query given the request posted in the url.

I have tried `time.sleep()` and using `urllib2.Request()` and `.urlopen()` to try and capture the changes when the page loads but with no success.

Does anyone know how to let `urllib2` get content on subsequent pages #qmpage2, #qmpage3, ...  ?

Answer (score 1):

From inspecting the page, it appears that all the pages of news are rendered on every request; the hash for the page number appears to trigger javascript which determines which "page" of news gets displayed. You should be able to access all of the news stories with a single request (with BeautifulSoup, you can get the containing element for all news pages with `news = contents.find_all(class_="newsheadlines")` and parse individual pages from there).

Comment: The problem that I had is the string contents that I download into content only has the elements of the first page.  The only data for the subsequent pages shows up in text as <div id="page2" class="pages" style="display:none;"></div>.  I need to find a way to expand all of these sections before I read the HTML.

Comment: Interesting! I'm not sure what the best solution is, then. You might need something like selenium.

Comment: Selenium might do it.  In the end, I used a VB script and "Microsoft Internet Explorer"  controls.  This opened the webpage and gave access to all of the links that were not rendered.  And yes, 1 request was able to access all the stories.  Thanks for your advice.